# What's the deal with the end-game/post-credits/Floors 26-30 of Etrian Odyssey 2?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-2

I just beat Overlord on Floor 25, then I got a nice wrap up, end credits, and bam, back to title screen.  Yet when I look around online I see that the game goes on for another 5 floors and there is a "true" last boss.  The game really gives no indication (unless I just missed it) that the player is supposed to return to the game after the end credits roll.

What is the purpose of these 5 floors?  Why do they come after the credits instead of just making the game 5 floors longer?  I'm pretty satisfied with Etrian Odyssey 2 (ready to move on to 3), so I'd like to know if I can safely move on without missing much, or if it's like a vital/major part of the game to go up through Floor 30 to the "true" last boss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Etrian Odyssey* post-game dungeons are for people that want a harder game, or really enjoy copying other people's Internet advice. They do extend the plot, but it's not like you won't understand *Etrian Odyssey III* if you skip *II*'s post-game (or even the entire game).

They come after the credits because RPGs almost always put more things to do after the credits.

If you're happy where *II* ended, go onto *III* - *II* is a relatively poor game and *III* is much better anyway.